# "I hope it will be useful for you like" + verb

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-requests

I'm writing down few notes about a technical argument, I'm doing it also to understand them better, so in my intro I'm saying:

> If you are reading this, I hope it will be useful for you like writing
>   it was for me.

Mostrly my doubts are about the second part of the sentence:

> like writing it was for me

Does it sound correct in English? There is a more correct way to express this thought?

Comment: It doesn't sound too off to me. Maybe include a comma: "...useful for you, like writing it was for me."

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say "I hope that reading this will be as useful for you as writing it was for me."

Comment: Yeah, having an 'if' in there sounds weird since it is obviously the case. Saying "if" when assuming a positive response is not uncommon in other languages, but it sounds off in English. 

For reasons I can't articulate, this sentence definitely requires an 'as' comparison instead of a 'like' comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think many people would quibble about the grammaticality of the slight rewrite

> If you are reading this, I hope it will be useful for you, as writing
>   it was for me.

This usage note from [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/like) seems to license the version with 'like':

> It was [once] thought that *as* rather than *like* should be used to
>   mean 'in the same way that', but now both *as* and *like* are
>   acceptable: they hunt and catch fish as/like their ancestors used to.

The difference is that in the Collins example, the reading may well be that the methods rather than the hunting / fishing societies are being said to be comparable. Perhaps in OP's example 'like' is being stretched a little too far for some people.

Comment: Sorry for pinging you here - don't know how else to do it! Are you going to sign-on to Linguistics Beta, where your Grice/Sperber & Wilson post is living so that people can message you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Edwin, as non-native English speaker I'm always worried that my sentences sound too "exotic". Beside the 'like/as', do you think my sentence sounds right?

Comment: Perhaps I'd try to choose a way of saying it that didn't emphasise the mechanics of writing when you mean the whole process. _If you are reading this, I hope it will be as useful for you as crystallising my thoughts in writing was for me._

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_tastes_good_like_a_cigarette_should